# Format all Hard Drives within Domain

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, windows-domain

I am currently running a domain with Windows Server 2012 R2 as the DC. Is there a way I can format every single hard drive within the domain then fill all the drives with useless data so the original information isn't easily recoverable? The goal is the create a security application that I can trigger in the event there is a break in.

Comment: This seems like a pretty silly idea.  If there is a breakin, wouldn't the attackers just turn off the power?  Better solution:  Setup full disk encryption, just computers off when they are not in use.

Comment: Encrypt!  Data on formatted drive is still recoverable!

Comment: I think you need to think this through: 1. Are robbers going to patiently wait for your format and re-write to finish before unplugging? 2. How is it going to trigger? The cost of a false alarm is astronomical! 3. What about machines that are powered down? Encryption is the key here.

Answer (score 2):

Run full disk encryption and in case of break-in just wipe the data or use a program like [RDFC](http://www.bertel.de/software/rdfc/index-en.html) to overwrite important files.